# How to setup UserControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties

In an application I have the (simplified) task:

The application manages information about persons. The persons are stored somewhere (doesn't matter).
The user can add and remove persons to the list.

The list of persons (that is used quite often in the program) looks like this:

```
<UserControl>
...
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"
            SelectionMode="Single"/>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Add Person" Command="{Binding AddPersonCommand}" />
            <Button Content="Remove Person" Command="{Binding RemovePersonCommand}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
...
</UserControl>
```

Behind that works a ViewModel that I want to use for implementation.

Now I want wo have this control embedded into another Control/Window like this:

```
<personcontrol:PersonControl PersonsCollectionDP="{Binding PersonsFromMainVM}" SelectedPersonDP="{Binding SelectedPersonFromMainVM}" />
```

(*PersonsVM* and *SelectedPersonVM* are Properties in the VM of the UC/Window that embeds the PersonControl-UC, *PersonsDP* and *SelectedPersonDP* are DependencyProperty of the PersonControl-UC.)

I have the problem having the properties of the UC as a DependencyProperty and (at the same time) having as Properties in the UC-ViewModel.

How can I accomplish that?

---

**UPDATE 1**

Found [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/85408409-2430-48bc-bba0-456b63851921/best-way-to-create-an-usercontrol-with-dependency-properties-following-the-mvvmprinciple?forum=wpf) where exactly my problem is discussed but still not answered. Maybe someone has a new idea...

Answer (score 0):

It is all about datacontext. You could keep the bindings in usercontrol definition and later in parts where you embed your UC bind datacontext to a corresponding VM which provides your datasource of persons.

```
<Window>
    <personcontrol:PersonControl DataContext="{Binding PersonsVM}" />
</Window>
```

And in VM you would have

```
public class WindowVM 
{
   public PersonsUCProviderVM PersonsVM {get;set;}
}

public class PersonsVM
{
   public List<Person> Persons {get;set;}
   public Person SelectedPerson {get;set;}
   public ICommand AddPersonCommand {get;set;}
   public ICommand RemovePersonCommand {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: OK, so you want to hold a UC-VM in the MainWindow-VM... But what if the UC and the MainWindow (and the corresponding VM's) are implemented by different people? The MainWindowVM-programmer should not see the details of the UC-VM. He just wants to use it like every other UC and bind his VM-Properties to the DPs of the UC

Comment: If you want to make it a reusable control then you should operate through dependency properties. Create a VM for that UC (as you probably did). Wire up events when DP changes and according to them update local VM. When local VM's selected person changes, change the dependency property as well. Just make sure your VM knows about control (but that is a break of MVVM pattern). Reusable controls should not use VM's. Just plain codebehind as there is no need to have a VM at all.

Comment: _Reusable controls should not use VM's. Just plain codebehind as there is no need to have a VM at all._ -- It's hard for me believing that... Do you have some arguments for that? What about really complex UC's?

Comment: In my opinion UC's are lightweight reusable components. If you have a UC or complex UC which uses a VM it is already a View not a UC. And thus view should follow guidelines for own domain. Moreover, in most cases UC's do not have their own data sets. They use bound or notation defined data sources like ListBox. Even TreeView is called View because it is more than a UC - it wraps bound collection with additional data and features. Finally, databinding and VM for a UC is just an overhead IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

usually you use elementname binding when working with usercontrol and DP.(never set the DataContext to self)

```
<personcontrol:PersonControl PersonsCollectionDP="{Binding PersonsFromMainVM}" SelectedPersonDP="{Binding SelectedPersonFromMainVM}" />
```

then your usercontrol stuff should look like this

```
<UserControl x:Name="uc">
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=PersonsCollectionDP}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=SelectedPersonDP}"
        SelectionMode="Single"/>
</StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: So that means you would expose my ViewModel as DP? I gave it a try with `<personcontrol:PersonControl PersonsDP.Persons="{Binding PersonsFromMainVM}"/>` but that does not compile: "The property PersonsDP.Persons does not exist in XML namespace ..."

Comment: i just change the Usercontrol xaml, your mainwindow xaml is "ok". all i want to say is that you bind dependency properties wich are defined within the usercontrol with elementname binding (or relativesource binding). and i just gues that your PersonsDP DP is type of  PersonVM because you bind to it. <personcontrol:PersonControl PersonsDP="{Binding PersonVM}"/>. WITHIN YOUR USERCONTROL you bind to your USERCONTROL DPs!

Comment: I see I misguided you... I edited my post to clarify: PersonsDP is a DP but not of Type PersonVM. I only want to expose the Persons-Collection as DP... So how do I bind to the DPs from the MainWindow-xaml??

Comment: you have to bind the PROPERTIES not DP from your mainwindowVIEWMODEL to the DPs of your UserControl